# animation works on browser but not in android ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I am applying animation class from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ in my html.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" class="{{pageClass}}"></ion-view>
```

Now, In app.js

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toStateParams, fromState, fromStateParams) {
    if(fromState.name === 'bill' && toState.name === 'menu'){
        $rootScope.pageClass='animated slideInUp'
    }
});
```

Which means that apply the animation class only if I am going from bill to menu and not otherwise.

It works as expected in my browser but not in android. It does not seem to apply the animation when going from bill state to menu state.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried adding the comment on the element (instead of via js) to verify the animation works?

Comment: yes yes. definitely. I did that